Are sages also classified as tamasic?
Padma purana Uttara Khanda chapter 235 verse 26-30
Here Lord Vishnu to approach 10 tamasic sages Kaṇāda, Gautama, Śakti, Upamanyu, Jaimini, Kapila, Durvāsas, Mṛkaṇḍu, Bṛhaspati, Bhārgava and Jāmadagnya  and ask them to narrate tamasa puranas to demons and lead them astray..
Is there a classification of sages(Sattvik Tamasic etc) like classification of puranas?

Yes, Padma Purana classifies Puranas into 3 groups - Sattvika (which glorifying Vishnu), Rajasika (for glorifying Brahma) & Tamasika (for glorifying Shiva). However, this list appears to be a sectarian forgery, because the Puranas that are listed to glorify Brahma (like Brahmanda & Brahmavaivarta) don't contain a single line on that matter.

Not Puranas sir Sages

As per Manu Smriti, Sages (Rishis) are produced from second level of Sattva (goodness). See the verses given below:


12.46. Kings and Kshatriyas, the domestic priests of kings, and those who delight in the warfare of disputations (constitute) the middling
(rank of the) states caused by Activity.
12.47. The Gandharvas, the Guhyakas, and the servants of the gods, likewise the Apsarases, (belong all to) the highest (rank of)
conditions produced by Activity
12.48. Hermits, ascetics, Brahmanas, the crowds of the Vaimanika deities, the lunar mansions, and the Daityas (form) the first (and
lowest rank of the) existences caused by Goodness.
12.49. Sacrificers, the sages, the gods, the Vedas, the heavenly lights, the years, the manes, and the Sadhyas (constitute) the second
order of existences, caused by Goodness.

In these verses,Sattva is translated as Goodness and Rajas as Activity.
